# Convert google sheet to PDF then email daily

Tags: pdf, google-sheets

does anyone know the google script code so that I can convert a Google Sheet into a PDF then email it to one single email address (mine) at a set time daily?

The information is only in column A and up to row 30 (may increase or decrease depending on the tasks I have on hand - sheet is my task list!)

Not a techie here but know the importance of code in making life more efficient, so I would like to try implementing it myself. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Code may help you it worked great with me !

[Github Link](https://gist.github.com/gregorynicholas/9008572)

Note: the code make all Spreadsheet into pdf because there's no way to get just a sheet depends my infos if i'm not wrong

if you want to Convert just do this trick:
create another Spreadsheet with one sheet and do import range and don't forget to add the ID of new Spreadsheet on the code !

i had problem like that and this is how i solved it